# What are the issues followed by; when there is no logout in struts2 web app

Tags: jakarta-ee, struts2, logout, session-timeout

I had developed a web app which has no login and no logout but I have lot of session to handle and the reason for which I don't have login snd log out was, there was a net application which was running already and I was instructed to integrate this struts2 web app with that. so I did that and every thing goes fine but I am afraid that those session I had created was not cleared since I don't have logout. So I this case how to handle session. On internet I found some solutions like using window.onunload or using session-timeout in web.xml. I don't know which is best to use.

Answer (score 1):

If you need to share (part of) a session between .NET and Java EE, you can use a Service as described in this [Community Wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/834667/java-ee-integration-with-net-for-authentication)

.NET manage the authentication, Java EE calls .NET to check if the user is authenticated.

When the user logouts from .NET, the next call by Java EE will return "logged out".

Hope that helps

Comment: I like your solution and I need to use it since I need some thing other than setting session time out in web.xml. But I'm not aware for web services and I'm new to .Net

Comment: You can find many examples on the web, but you will have to study a little... they're both huge topics;

Thanks to @Arjan for editing, "Old habits die hard" :)

Answer (score 1):

Beside what is have been said above, a mechanism for session auto-cleaning is a best practice, and unless you have a specific need for an unlimited time session, they doesn't need to hung around for a long time.

Answer (score 1):

I use the session-timeout in web.xml and it works well. You just need to figure out what's the right delay to get rid of the session to not bother users with too shorts session and not slowing your server with too many sessions.

I develop applications for small amount of users so I put whatever I want in my session and let it timeout hours later. It's not small amount of text that will overload our servers.